# Fixing the min-heap after subtracting a value from a couple random elements in it

Tags: data-structures, heaps

> Given a Min-Heap with $n$ elements. 
> Assume that we choose $\lceil \log_2n \rceil$ elements from the heap (not in any specific order/index's), and we subtract a value $k>0$ from all of their keys. 
> Suggest an algorithm to fix the min-heap that runs in $O((\log_2n)^2)$.

**My thoughts:** 
In a min heap the key value of children nodes is bigger or equal to the parent. 
Which means when we subtract a positive value from a key of a node, we may have a child with a key value less than it's parent and we need to switch between them. 
My main problem is how to locate those nodes that I need to fix their position in the heap? This seems somehow impossible to me without going through all the nodes of the heap which will cost $O(n)$. 
I would appreciate any help and hints in how to locate these nodes, since when I locate them I could just do the DecreaseKey function in a min-heap which brings the child up to it's correct place (keeps switching between the child and parent until we get a child key value greater or equal than the parent or we reach the root of the heap). 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should assumed that the positions of these elements in the heap a known.

Answer (score 2):

First you remove the O(log n) items from the heap. You can do this by finding their indices then removing them starting with the highest index. Make sure that your removal algorithm doesn’t move any items at lower indices.

Then you modify the keys any way you like and move them back into the heap. Operations on the heap run in O(log n), and there are O(log n) of them. You should have code for adding or removing an item, so you don’t need to care about the details.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if the last item is the root we would do O(nlogn) by finding and removing.. Im not sure if theres a problem with the question and we should get their positions in order for it to be solvable according to the comment I got.